# Taking out Big O terms in the numerator and denominator as a single Big O term

Tags: calculus, analysis, numerical-methods, asymptotics

I am having difficulty understanding how to deal with the big O term in the denominator of a fraction while reading a paper.

The form of the fraction is given by $$\frac{a+ b h^k + O(h^{k+2})}{c + d h^k + O(h^{k+2})}$$ and the result is given as $\frac{a+b h^k}{c + d h^k} + O(h^{2k})$.

How do we get rid of the $O(h^{k+2})$ terms each in the numerator and the denominator and take them out as a term $O(h^{2k})$? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Are there some hypothesis on $a,b,c,d$?  Are them constants with respect to $h$?

Comment: @SilvioM They are just some integral values

Comment: what do you mean by integral values? Defined by integrals? Or do you mean integers? In order to understanding what's going on it is fundamental to understand if these values are considered constants wrt $h$ or not

Comment: @SilvioM Sorry I meant they don't depend on $h$.

Comment: This is false. Assuming $c \ne 0$, the correct expression would be $\frac{a+b h^k}{c + d h^k} + O(h^{k+2})$. Unless there is more known about the actual function than just the original fractional expression, there is nothing that guarantees the $O$ portion of the simplified form will go to $0$ any faster than $h^{k+2}$. If it is known that $k \le 2$, then $O(h^{k+2})$ also qualifies as $O(h^{2k})$, so it holds in that case, but it does not hold for $k > 2$/